# Get Oracle view code information using oracle toad

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I want to see the code of preexisting view in query window itself without going Schema Browser or directly going to that object. How to see view code in Oracle TOAD?

We can see using below script in SQL Server

```
sp_helptext 'viewname'
```

In Oracle I have tried like below

```
select * from USER_SOURCE where Name ='viewname'
```

but its not giving viewname code information. How to achieve this task in Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_emp
  2  as
  3  select d.deptno,
  4         d.dname,
  5         e.empno,
  6         e.ename,
  7         e.job,
  8         e.sal
  9  from emp e join dept d
 10    on e.deptno = d.deptno
 11  where d.deptno <> 30;

View created.
```

You were querying `USER_SOURCE`, but that view doesn't contain views - check `USER_VIEWS` instead. Query, similar to yours, doesn't return anything:

```
SQL> select text
  2  from user_views
  3  where view_name = 'v_emp';

no rows selected
```

Why *no rows selected*? Because Oracle stores object names in **UPPERCASE** by default unless you enclosed the name into double quotes, but - in Oracle - that's generally a bad idea as you'd always have to reference objects with double quotes, matching letter case. By default, you can reference them any way you want.

So:

```
SQL> select text
  2  from user_views
  3  where view_name = 'V_EMP';        --> note uppercase here

TEXT
----------------------------------------------------------------
select d.deptno,
       d.dname,
       e.empno,
       e.ename,
       e.job,



SQL>
```

But hey! Part of code is missing! That's **SQL Plus**, though. As view text is stored into a `LONG` datatype column:

```
SQL> desc user_views
 Name                          Null?    Type
 ----------------------------- -------- --------------------
 VIEW_NAME                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 TEXT_LENGTH                            NUMBER
 TEXT                                   LONG           --> here it is
 TYPE_TEXT_LENGTH                       NUMBER 
 <snip>
```

you'd then

```
SQL> set long 10000
SQL> select text
  2  from user_views
  3  where view_name = 'V_EMP';

TEXT
----------------------------------------------------------------
select d.deptno,
       d.dname,
       e.empno,
       e.ename,
       e.job,
       e.sal
from emp e join dept d
  on e.deptno = d.deptno
where d.deptno <> 30


SQL>
```

and see the whole view code.

---

In **TOAD**, the result is a `WIDEMEMO` column so you'll have to double-click it to view the result (without using the `SET LONG` command; it is related to SQL*Plus only).

Answer (score 0):

The view code will be present in user_views table in oracle. you can achieve this by using the query

```
SELECT * FROM user_views WHERE VIEW_NAME= UPPER('viewname')
```